# Pillow library - GIF distorted while loop over the gif and pasting another image on it

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I am working with a Pillow library. I have one gif on which I have to paste another image.
While loop over every frames of the gif and pasting image on it, gif distorted.

Someone please suggest a proper solution for it.

Thanks.

**1. GIF**

[image]

**2. Image**

[image]

**3. Code**

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

animated_gif = './img/gif_distort.gif'
transparent_foreground = './img/cat.jpeg'

img = Image.open(animated_gif)
image = Image.open(transparent_foreground)

duration = []
frames = []

for i in range(img.n_frames):
    img.seek(i)
    frame = img.convert('RGBA').copy()
    duration.append(img.info['duration'])
    frame.paste(image)
    frames.append(frame)

# save gif in temp file
temp_gif_path = 'img/output.gif'
frames[0].save(temp_gif_path, format='GIF', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], duration=duration, optimise=True)
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Pillow. If you call `getpalette()` on each frame, it seems to assume that the palette is the same for all frames whereas the image actually has a different palette for each frame.

Comment: I submitted an issue on Github https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4977

Comment: I've created a pull request to fix this - https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/5857

Comment: This problem be resolved as of Pillow 9.0.0, released on January 1.